# Left coset of H in $A_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This problem arises in problem 1 of Chapter 7 of Contemporary abstract algebra by Joseph Gallian.
This problem requires the use of Table 5.1 on page 104 of Chapter 5 and I am unable to replicate the table within reasonable bounds.

> Definition:
>
> The left coset of the subgroup H of a  group G containing the element g in G is the set $gH=\left \{ gh\mid h \in H \right \}$.

I am facing great difficulty understanding the table.

Here's my attempt:

$A_{4}=\left \{ 1,2,3,4 \right \}$

$\left ( 1 \right )H=\left \{ \left ( 1 \right ) ,\left ( 12 \right )\left ( 34 \right ),\left ( 13 \right )\left ( 24 \right ),\left ( 14 \right )\left ( 23 \right )\right \}
=\left \{ \alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\alpha_{3},\alpha_{4} \right \}$

This is correct.

Now,

$\left ( 2 \right )H=\left \{ \left ( 2 \right )\left ( 1  \right ),\left ( 2 \right )\left ( 12 \right )\left ( 34 \right ),\left ( 2 \right )\left ( 13 \right )\left ( 24 \right ),\left ( 2 \right )\left ( 14 \right )\left ( 23 \right )\right \} $

The solution given is

$\alpha_{5}H=\left \{ \alpha_{5},\alpha_{8},\alpha_{6},\alpha_{7} \right \}$

Which looks nothing like my attempt of $\left ( 2 \right )H$

Would someone shed some light? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't look like any $\;A_4\;$ I know of...perhaps you meant the alternating group of order $\;12\;$ ? And what are those $\;\alpha_i\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo No, I meant the book mean it to be $A_{4}$.
"The Alternating group $A_{4}$ of Even permutations of ${1,2,3,4}$.
I wish I could replicate the table but the table is of a 12x12 matrix.

Comment: But then $\;A_4\;$ is **not** what you wrote, but the subgroup of order $\;12\;$ in $\;S_4\;$ .

Comment: The elements of $A_4$, other than the elements of $H$, are the 3-cycles, of which there are eight. E.g., $(123)$ is an element of $A_4$, and one of the cosets you want to calculate is $(123)H$.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.